# Query about @bitmap binary(1) in TSQL?

Tags: t-sql

In one of the stored procedures in TSQL I came across the code

```
Alter procedure Name
@parameter1 ,
@parameter2 ,
..........


if (substring(@bitmap,1,1) & 1 = 1) or  //what does this mean?
 (substring(@bitmap,1,1) & 2 = 2) or
 (substring(@bitmap,1,1) & 4 = 4) or
 (substring(@bitmap,1,1) & 128 = 128) or
 (substring(@bitmap,2,1) & 1 = 1)

[Column1] = case substring(@bitmap,1,1) & 1 when 1 then @parameter1 else [Column1] end,
[Column2] = case substring(@bitmap,1,1) & 2 when 2 then @parameter2 else [Column2] end,
[Column3] = case substring(@bitmap,1,1) & 4 when 4 then @parameter3 else [Column3] end,
[Column4] = case substring(@bitmap,1,1) & 8 when 8 then @parameter4 else [Column4] end,
[Column5] = case substring(@bitmap,1,1) & 16 when 16 then @parameter5 else [Column5] end,
[Column6] = case substring(@bitmap,1,1) & 32 when 32 then @parameter6 else [Column6] end,
[Column7] = case substring(@bitmap,1,1) & 64 when 64 then @parameter7 else [Column7]end,
[Column8] = case substring(@bitmap,1,1) & 128 when 128 then @parameter8 else [Column8] end,
[Column9] = case substring(@bitmap,2,1) & 1 when 1 then @parameter9 else [Column9] end,
[Column10] = case substring(@bitmap,2,1) & 2 when 2 then @parameter10 else [Column10] end
```

Googling this i found that it helps to dynamically build the procedure. But I still have few doubts.

```
(substring(@bitmap,1,1) & 1 = 1) or  //what does this mean?
substring(@bitmap,2,1) & 1 when 1 then @parameter9 else [Column9] end,//what does this mean

case SUBSTRING(@bitmap,1,1) & 256 when 256 or
case SUBSTRING(@bitmap,1,1) & 512 when 512
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@bitmap is a bitmask which defines which of the @parameterN values is used to overwrite the (existing?) values of the ColumnN values.

The expression `(value & x) when x` checks whether a given bit is set in the @bitmap for x being a power of 2.

The expression `CASE expression WHEN value THEN x ELSE y END` is equivalent to the IF ELSE statement (or if/switch in C# etc.).

Comment: what is the maximum value x can have,is it 128 or can i use 254,512. And what is the difference between (@bitmap,1,1) and (@bitmap,2,1). (substring(@bitmap,1,1) & 1 = 1) does this mean 1st parameter and so on

Comment: Just for completeness: `(value & x) when x` checks that all of the bits set in `x` are also set in `value`.  The OP's question happens to use powers of two, but that isn't a requirement.

Comment: I am confused between if substring(@bitmap,1,1) & 128 = 128 and 
                      if substring(@bitmap,2,1) & 128 = 128

Comment: the highest value is 128 (bit 7), therefore substring(@bitmap,2,1) etc must be used to address more than 8 parameters